# Connect to bolt server failed

Tags: neo4j, bolt

When I try to run the simplest html page that will show me graph of neo4j data, using neovis.js:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DataViz</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #viz {
                width: 900px;
                height: 700px;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://cdn.neo4jlabs.com/neovis.js/v1.0.0/neovis.js"></script>
    </head>   
    <script>
        function draw() {
            let config = {
                container_id: "viz",
                server_url: "bolt://54.210.87.221:32953",
                server_user: "neo4j",
                server_password: "cents-propeller-slits",
                labels: {
                    "Application": {
                        caption: "name",
                        size: "pagerank",
                        community: "community"
                    }
                },
                relationships: {
                    "DEPENDS_ON":{
                        caption: false,
                        thickness: "weight"
                    }
                },
                initial_cypher: "MATCH p=(Application)-[r:DEPENDS_ON]->() RETURN p LIMIT 25"
            };
            let viz = new NeoVis.default(config);
            viz.render();
        }
    </script>
    <body onload="draw()">
        <div id="viz"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get this error message at the console:

> "WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web
>   browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j
>   Driver. Please use your browsers development console to determine the
>   root cause of the failure. Common reasons include the database being
>   unavailable, using the wrong connection URL or temporary network
>   problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure your browser is
>   configured to trust the certificate Neo4j is configured to use.
>   WebSocket `readyState` is: 3"

I saw the answer in https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/explanation-of-error-websocket-connection-failure/
But I didn't understood where I suppose to do the change, specially when I do not have any Neo4j files or configurations on my computer (Windows).

Why can't I connect to the bolt server like I saw in the guides?

Answer (score 0):

Like the link said, you need to tell Neo4j to listen on the network.

For this you need to change the Neo4j configuration by enabeling the line `dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687` in the `$NEO4J_HOME/conf/neo4j.conf`.

So in your case you need to do that on your server `54.210.87.221`, not on your local laptop.

Cheers.

Comment: But where the $NEO4J_HOME/conf/neo4j.conf file is? it is not on my computer

Comment: you have to do it on the server side, so on your server located at `54.210.87.221`

Comment: I know that from your side I might sounds really stupid, but if is not a trouble for you - can you give me more specific instructions? I'm on that problem all day and I know that something is not right. I do not find the conf file, or able to connect to the direct HTTP neo4j: http://54.210.87.221:32954/browser/